# Choosing web service for iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, amazon-web-services

im currently making an iphone application that will be in need of a web service. And obviously im thinking about releasing it to appstore eventually. So my question is what kind of web service should i use that is "well known " or what normally people woould choose?

It does not have to be free just that its professional. Anyone has some tips?

I have been looking into amazon web services and im trying the 12 months free trial, and i cant seem to find any tutorial of how to upload some files that will produce a json text as a GET request. If anyone have some information regarding that or a tutorial that would also be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not happy/confident about developing server side code you could also consider using services such as Parse

https://www.parse.com

Answer (score 1):

You're asking some extremely open-ended questions for which there is no single good answer.

> So my question is what kind of web service should i use that is "well known " or what normally people woould choose?

There are plenty of "well known" web services to choose from.  First you need to decide if you want this to run on Windows or on linux, and the answer for that question depends mostly on what you are comfortable working with and what you're used to programming on.  If you're going the linux route then you further need to decide what linux distribution to use: RedHat, Ubuntu, Debian, Amazon, etc.

The answer to that question will then narrow down your choices of the actual "web service", be it IIS (Windows only), Apache, nginx, etc. And those answers will also depend on and/or help decide which programming language(s) you want to utilize: java, C#, python, ruby, perl, etc.

> i cant seem to find any tutorial of how to upload some files that will produce a json text as a GET request.

The reason you can't find such a tutorial is because it's going to depend greatly upon the answers to all the above questions.  If you want to implement this on Windows using IIS and C# then any tutorials are going to be specific to those choices.  If you want to implement this on linux using Apache and java then any tutorials are going to be specific to those choices, and significantly different from the Windows based tutorials.